# "Multiple definitions of" error while linking two archives using the same source file

Tags: gcc, compilation, linker, linker-errors, ld

I'm getting an error while linking two archives, for which the same source file `pci.h` has been used during the compilation:

```
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/anon/tp-link-gpl/wr841nv9_en_gpl/ap143/boot/u-boot/rtc'
UNDEF_SYM=`mips-linux-uclibc-objdump -x lib_generic/libgeneric.a common/libcommon.a board/atheros/board953x/libboard953x.a cpu/mips/libmips.a lib_mips/libmips.a drivers/libdrivers.a net/libnet.a rtc/librtc.a  |sed  -n -e 's/.*\(__u_boot_cmd_.*\)/-u\1/p'|sort|uniq`;\
    mips-linux-uclibc-ld -Bstatic -T /home/anon/tp-link-gpl/wr841nv9_en_gpl/ap143/boot/u-boot/board/atheros/board953x/u-boot.lds -Ttext 0x80010000  $UNDEF_SYM cpu/mips/start.o  /home/anon/tp-link-gpl/wr841nv9_en_gpl/ap143/boot/u-boot/board/atheros/board953x/extra.o \
        --start-group lib_generic/libgeneric.a common/libcommon.a board/atheros/board953x/libboard953x.a cpu/mips/libmips.a lib_mips/libmips.a drivers/libdrivers.a net/libnet.a rtc/librtc.a  --end-group -L /home/anon/tp-link-gpl/wr841nv9_en_gpl/build/gcc-4.3.3/build_mips/staging_dir/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/mips-openwrt-linux-musl/5.5.0 -lgcc \
        -Map u-boot.map -o u-boot

board/atheros/board953x/libboard953x.a(ath_pci.o): In function `pci_set_region':
/home/anon/tp-link-gpl/wr841nv9_en_gpl/ap143/boot/u-boot/include/pci.h:328: multiple definition of `pci_set_region'
drivers/libdrivers.a(pci.o):/home/anon/tp-link-gpl/wr841nv9_en_gpl/ap143/boot/u-boot/include/pci.h:328: first defined here

board/atheros/board953x/libboard953x.a(ath_pci.o): In function `pci_set_ops':
/home/anon/tp-link-gpl/wr841nv9_en_gpl/ap143/boot/u-boot/include/pci.h:421: multiple definition of `pci_set_ops'
drivers/libdrivers.a(pci.o):/home/anon/tp-link-gpl/wr841nv9_en_gpl/ap143/boot/u-boot/include/pci.h:421: first defined here

make[1]: *** [Makefile:217: u-boot] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/anon/tp-link-gpl/wr841nv9_en_gpl/ap143/boot/u-boot'
make: *** [Makefile:200: uboot] Error 2
```

Using #ifndef guard for these functions did not help. Please tell, how to resolve this problem?

Comment: `include/pci.h:328: first defined here` what is there?

Comment: @KamilCuk `extern __inline__ void pci_set_region(...)` function. This source file is used while building two archives, and during the linking stage they conflict. I tried adding ` --allow-multiple-definition` to LDFLAGS of u-boot's config.mk to bypass this step, but I don't know if it's a correct approach

Comment: `extern __inline__` - looks like a issue with inline, probably your compiler does not handle that well. See [gcc docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Inline.html) or a stackoverflow thread for exaplanations. `If you specify both inline and extern in the function definition, then the definition is used only for inlining.` - yet your compiler compiled the function on it's own and exported it's symbol.  Still, at `include/pci.h:328` there is a function definition or declaration? If it's a definition, maybe remove extern?

Comment: @KamilCuk Thank you very much, a compilation is working if I remove an `extern` or replace it with `static` for both of these functions. Please write it as an answer and I will accept it. Have a nice day ;-)